# aiogram inline кнопки не работают

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

кнопки не работают

```py
import logging
import asyncio
import random
import sqlite3
import string

#aiogram и всё утилиты для коректной работы с Telegram API
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram.utils.emoji import emojize
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.types.message import ContentType
from aiogram.utils.markdown import text, bold, italic, code, pre
from aiogram.types import ParseMode, InputMediaPhoto, InputMediaVideo, ChatActions
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardRemove,ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
import aiogram.utils.exceptions
from aiogram.types.message import ContentTypes

#конфиг с настройками
import config
from database import dbworker


#инициализируем базу данных
db = dbworker('db.db')

#инициализируем бота
bot = Bot(token=config.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot,storage=MemoryStorage())

#логирование
logging.basicConfig(filename="all_log.log", level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s -%(message)s')
warning_log = logging.getLogger("warning_log")
warning_log.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

fh = logging.FileHandler("warning_log.log")

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)


warning_log.addHandler(fh)

#хендлер команды /start
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'],state='*')
async def start(message : types.Message, state: FSMContext):

    await state.finish()

    button_search = KeyboardButton('Начать поиск')

    button_info_project = KeyboardButton('Всякая всячина')

    ranked = KeyboardButton('Рейтинг⭐️')

    count_users = KeyboardButton(f'В боте уже {int(db.count_user() * 1.5)} пользователей')

    mark_menu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup()

    mark_menu.add(button_search,button_info_project,ranked,count_users)

    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,' Привет!\n\nЯ Chatium, бот для анонимного общения\nИ чего ты ждёшь,давай начнём!\n\nТыкай на кнопки внизу, а там разберёмся\n\nНовости и мемные переписки - https://t.me/chatium_community \n\nЛамповое общения - https://t.me/chatium_chat',reply_markup=mark_menu)

#тут проблема
@dp.message_handler(lambda message : message.text == 'Всякая всячина' or message.text == 'О проекте‍' or message.text == 'Все ссылки на нас' or message.text == '[ Для разработчиков ]',state='*')
async def about_project(message : types.Message):
    if message.text == 'Всякая всячина':

        for_developers = KeyboardButton('[ Для разработчиков ]')

        back = KeyboardButton('Назад')

        rules = KeyboardButton('Правила')

        mark_menu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup()

        mark_menu.add(for_developers,rules,back)

        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Вся информация тут',reply_markup=mark_menu)

    elif message.text == '[ Для разработчиков ]':
        await message.answer('Если вы разработчик и хотите поучаствовать в разработке проекта то смело контрибутье на гите или пишите на почту - merlinincorp@gmail.com\n\nGithub - https://github.com/RenatYakublevich/AnonymChat')

@dp.message_handler(commands=['rules'],state='*')
@dp.message_handler(lambda message : message.text == 'Правила')
async def rules(message : types.Message):
    await message.answer('''Правила общения в @Chatium_Bot\n1. Любые упоминания психоактивных веществ. (наркотиков)\n2. Детская порнография. ("ЦП")\n3. Мошенничество. (Scam)\n4. Любая реклама, спам.\n5. Продажи чего либо. (например - продажа интимных фотографий, видео)\n6. Любые действия, нарушающие правила Telegram.\n7. Оскорбительное поведение.\n8. Обмен, распространение любых 18+ материалов\n\n''')
```

кнопки начинают работать как только становятся `Reply`, а мне нужно `Inline`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для Inline кнопок нужно использовать `callback_data` и `@dp.callback_query_handler`. Вот пример кода (**Все части которые не относятся к вопросу удалены**):

```py
# aiogram и всё утилиты для коректной работы с Telegram API
from aiogram import Bot, types, executor
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.types import KeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardMarkup
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

#конфиг с настройками
import config

# инициализируем бота
bot = Bot(token=config.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())


# хендлер команды /start
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'], state='*')
async def start(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.finish()

    button_search = KeyboardButton('Начать поиск')

    button_info_project = KeyboardButton('Всякая всячина')

    ranked = KeyboardButton('Рейтинг⭐️')

    count_users = KeyboardButton(f'В боте уже {int(1.5)} пользователей')

    mark_menu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup()

    mark_menu.add(button_search, button_info_project, ranked, count_users)

    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                           ' Привет!\n\nЯ Chatium, бот для анонимного общения\nИ чего ты ждёшь,'
                           'давай начнём!\n\nТыкай на кнопки внизу, а там разберёмся\n\nНовости и мемные переписки - '
                           'https://t.me/chatium_community \n\nЛамповое общения - https://t.me/chatium_chat',
                           reply_markup=mark_menu)


# тут проблема
@dp.callback_query_handler(text=["stuff", "developers", "rules"])
async def about_project(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    if call.data == "developers":
        await call.message.answer(
            'Если вы разработчик и хотите поучаствовать в разработке проекта то смело контрибутье на гите или пишите '
            'на почту - merlinincorp@gmail.com\n\nGithub - https://github.com/RenatYakublevich/AnonymChat')
    elif call.data == "rules":
        await call.message.answer(
            '''Правила общения в @Chatium_Bot\n1. Любые упоминания психоактивных веществ. (наркотиков)\n2. Детская 
            порнография. ("ЦП")\n3. Мошенничество. (Scam)\n4. Любая реклама, спам.\n5. Продажи чего либо. (например - 
            продажа интимных фотографий, видео)\n6. Любые действия, нарушающие правила Telegram.\n7. Оскорбительное 
            поведение.\n8. Обмен, распространение любых 18+ материалов\n\n''')
    await call.answer()


@dp.message_handler(text=['Всякая всячина'])
async def inline_events(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == "Всякая всячина":
        for_developers = KeyboardButton('[ Для разработчиков ]', callback_data="developers")

        back = KeyboardButton('Назад', callback_data="back")

        rules_btn = KeyboardButton('Правила', callback_data="rules")

        mark_menu = InlineKeyboardMarkup()

        mark_menu.add(for_developers, rules_btn, back)

        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вся информация тут', reply_markup=mark_menu)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['rules'], state='*')
async def rules(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(
        '''Правила общения в @Chatium_Bot\n1. Любые упоминания психоактивных веществ. (наркотиков)\n2. Детская 
        порнография. ("ЦП")\n3. Мошенничество. (Scam)\n4. Любая реклама, спам.\n5. Продажи чего либо. (например - 
        продажа интимных фотографий, видео)\n6. Любые действия, нарушающие правила Telegram.\n7. Оскорбительное 
        поведение.\n8. Обмен, распространение любых 18+ материалов\n\n''')


executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Comment: а что делать если нужен ответ накнопку Reply текстом с кнопками inline тоесть чоб на кнопку Reply отвечал уведомлениям с inline кнопками

Comment: @Undryck Для reply продолжайте использовать `@dp.message_handler` (**В отдельной функции**) как в вашем коде

Comment: прошу вас если можете распишите детально что ви имели ввиду

Comment: @Undryck исправил код для использования двух видов кнопок